# Different behavior of mySql compare to Ms-Sql and Oracle on joining the table with sorted result set

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

The following 2 tables exist:

T1 :

```
 ---------------
|  Id  |  Name  |
 ---------------
|  1   |  One   |
|  2   |  Two   |
|  3   |  Three |
 ---------------
```

T2:

```
 ----------------------
|  Id  |  Name  | T1Id |
 ----------------------
|  6   |   X    |   3  |
|  7   |   Y    |   2  |
|  8   |   Z    |   1  |
 ----------------------
```

Table one (T1) has the primary key column ‘Id’ with values 1, 2 and 3.
Table two (T2) has the primary key column ‘Id’ and also ‘T1Id’ foreign key column related to T1 table.
I’m trying to execute the following SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM T1 ORDER BY Id ASC) AS Tmp
INNER JOIN T2 ON Tmp.Id = T2.Level1Id
```

I’m wondering that although the first line is trying to order T1 and then join to T2 the result set is not sorted, the other DBMS s like Ms-SQL or Oracle do that.
The result set is:

Result:

```
 ----------------------------------------
|  Id  |  Name  |  Id  |  T1Id  |  Name  |
 ----------------------------------------
|  3   |  Three |   6  |    3   |   X    |
|  2   |  Two   |   7  |    2   |   Y    |
|  1   |  One   |   8  |    1   |   Z    |
 ----------------------------------------
```

Why this happens and what’s the reason?

Comment: *`the other DBMS s like SQL Server`* SQL Server does not that **`The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.`** For Orcale is not sorted either [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d7347/3/0). The point is without explicit `ORDER BY` in most outer query the order is not guarnateed. Period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL standard clearly says that the result set does not need to be in any particular order if you don't specify an `ORDER BY` for it.

Any "intermediate" `ORDER BY` on subselects or join inputs has no impact and can be ignored.

Without the specified ordering, the database is free to choose what order is most efficient to implement. That may in some cases be the same order as one of the join inputs (it would come out that way naturally in case of a nested loop join), but you cannot depend on that.

So if you want to get the result in a defined order, you have to put the `ORDER BY` on the top-most `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Would you please provide me a link to the SQL standard reference you have mentioned ?

Comment: The later revisions of the SQL standard are not freely available. Here is SQL-92, you can search for order by: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt  And I suppose that the documentation for the various RDBMS products also contains language to this effect.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM T1 AS Tmp
INNER JOIN T2 ON Tmp.Id = T2.Level1Id
ORDER BY Tmp.Id ASC
```

Comment: I don't want the solution. I try to find out the reason.